Alembic generates all models at revision
I am trying to run alembic on a database where there are about 20 tables that are created by sqlalchemy models. I am using 5 schemas to keep the tables separate from each other. When I run alembic revision --autogenerate it finds changes in all tables and keys.
Init revision:
"""Init

"""

revision: str = 'd186eaea84ed'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = None
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    pass


def downgrade() -> None:
    pass

next revision (autogenerated):
revision: str = '869b45c3c83e'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = 'd186eaea84ed'
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('data',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('pocet_dokumentov', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('nazov_materialu', sa.Text(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('typ_materialu', sa.Text(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('datum_dorucenia', sa.Date(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('navrhovatelia', sa.Text(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('pozmenovaci_navrh', sa.Text(), nullable=True),
...
...
...
def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_constraint('result_filtre_id_filter_fkey', 'result_filtre', schema='public', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_foreign_key('result_filtre_id_filter_fkey', 'result_filtre', 'filtre', ['id_filter'], ['id'], onupdate='CASCADE')
    op.drop_constraint('prepojenia_id_slovlex_fkey', 'prepojenia', schema='public', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint('prepojenia_id_vlada_fkey', 'prepojenia', schema='public', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint('prepojenia_id_nrsr_fkey', 'prepojenia', schema='public', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_foreign_key('prepojenia_id_nrsr_fkey', 'prepojenia', 'data', ['id_nrsr'], ['id'], referent_schema='nrsr', onupdate='CASCADE')
    op.create_foreign_key('prepojenia_id_vlada_fkey', 'prepojenia', 'data', ['id_vlada'], ['id'], referent_schema='vlada', onupdate='CASCADE')
    op.create_foreign_key('prepojenia_id_slovlex_fkey', 'prepojenia', 'data', ['id_slovlex'], ['id'], referent_schema='slovlex', onupdate='CASCADE')
    op.drop_table('KPIs_hodnoty', schema='odpocty')
...
...

I tried creating an empty migration and used stamp instead of upgrade.
I also used configure_mappers() and still had the same problem.
As far as I know it should only generate changes between the database and sqlalchemy models.

https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_schemas
